# Slice method with condition within loop in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, slice

I want to render 0 to 3 items if a state is false and 4 to end of array length if state is true by clicking `See more`

I have the following piece of code but it's erroring out:

```
{items
                .filter((item) => DateTime.fromISO(item.date).year === lastYear)
                **.slice(showArticles ? (4, items.length) : (0, 3))**
                .map((filteredItem) => (
                        <div>
                            <date>{filteredItem.date}</date>
                            <span>{filteredItem.article}</div>
                        </div>

                ))}
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    showArticles;
                }}
            >
                See more
            </button>
```

The current slice condition is making it so nothing is rendered.
How can I show my items accordingly?

Answer (score 5):

You can spread an array of args into the `slice` method. Remember that the ending index is excluded, so if you want elements 0-3 then specify `slice(0, 4)`.

[Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The **`slice()`** method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
> into a new array object selected from `start` to `end` (***`end` not included***)
> where `start` and `end` represent the index of items in that array. The
> original array will not be modified.

```
items.filter((item) => DateTime.fromISO(item.date).year === lastYear)
  .slice(...(showArticles ? [4] : [0, 4])) // 4 through the end, or 0 to 3
  .map((filteredItem) => (....
```

```js
function App() {
  const [showArticles, setShowArticles] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowArticles((s) => !s)}>
        Toggle
      </button>

      {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i)
        .slice(...(showArticles ? [4] : [0, 4]))
        .map((el) => (
          <li key={el}>{el}</li>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are having an extra `()` inside the slice, this should to it:**

```
{items
  .filter((item) => DateTime.fromISO(item.date).year === lastYear)
  .slice(showArticles ? 4 : 0, showArticles ? items.length : 3)
  .map((filteredItem) => (
          <div>
              <date>{filteredItem.date}</date>
              <span>{filteredItem.article}</div>
          </div>

))}
```